# How can I execute multiple commands using Salt Stack?

Tags: salt-stack

I tried to add:

```
 mypack:
   pkg:
     - installed
     - pkgs:
       - mercurial
       - git
   cmd.run:
       - name: 'mkdir -p /opt/mypack'
   cmd.run: 'hg pull -u -R /opt/mypack || hg clone -R /opt https://...'
   cmd.run: 'ln -s /opt/mypack/etc/init.d/xxx /etc/init.d/xxx'
```

But for some reason this the state seems to execute/install but the commands are not executed, or at least not all of them.

I need a solution to run multiple commands and to fail the deployment if any of these fails.

I know that I could write a bash script and include this bash script, but I was looking for a solution that would work with only the YAML file.

Comment: EDIT:  Nevermind, apparently I can't post code blocks in comments.  I guess I'll leave a real answer.

Comment: Hey sorin, is this question answered?

Comment: Another year, another prod to sorin to accept an answer.

Answer (score 57):

You want this:

```
cmd-test:
  cmd.run:
    - name: |
        mkdir /tmp/foo
        chown dan /tmp/foo
        chgrp www-data /tmp/foo
        chmod 2751 /tmp/foo
        touch /tmp/foo/bar
```

Or this, which I would prefer, where the script is downloaded from the master:

```
cmd-test:
  cmd.script:
    - source: salt://foo/bar.sh
    - cwd: /where/to/run
    - user: fred
```

Comment: One reason the second version is better is that the logs end up cleaner - otherwise the entire text of the embedded script appears (jammed onto one line) several times in the output log.

Comment: Thanks SteveBennett.  I'm hoping @sorin would mark my answer as a solution.

Comment: Why I can't find a mention of `-name: |` in Salt's documentation? Not very googleable, ok.

Comment: @giorgiosironi That's a way in YAML to specify a multi-line inline value. You're not seeing it in Salt's docs because it's not specific to Salt.

Comment: Caveat: what you probably want to do here is to place `&&` between commands so that execution is stopped on the first one that fails.

Answer (score 15):

In addition to the above (better) suggestions, you can do this:

```
cmd-test:
  cmd.run:
    - names: 
      - mkdir -p /opt/mypack
      - hg pull -u -R /opt/mypack || hg clone -R /opt https://...
      - ln -s /opt/mypack/etc/init.d/xxx /etc/init.d/xxx
```

For reasons I don't understand yet (I'm a Salt novice), the `names` are iterated in reverse order, so the commands are executed backwards.

Comment: I don't think it's that they're in reverse order, just that the actual YAML ordering of items in a list is arbitrary, and you never know how it's going to see them

Comment: @ThrillScience It's not YAML (lists are guaranteed to be ordered) but 'names' is special.  It actually generates individual cmd.run states for each of the specified names.  You can verify this by running `salt-call state.show_sls --out=yaml whatever`.  See https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/highstate.html#names-declaration  The reversed state order was a 'names' implementation bug which I believe has been fixed.

Answer (score 4):

You can do as Dan pointed out, using the pipe or a `cmd.script` state.  But it should be noted that you have some syntax problems in your original post.  Each new state needs a `name` arg, you can't just put the command after the colon:

```
mypack:
  pkg:
    - installed
    - pkgs:
      - mercurial
      - git
  cmd.run:
    - name: 'my first command'
  cmd.run:
    - name: 'my second command'
```

However, that actually may fail as well, because I don't think you can put multiple of the same state underneath a single ID.  So you may have to split them out like this:

```
first:
  cmd.run:
    - name: 'my first command'

second:
  cmd.run:
    - name: 'my second command'
```

Comment: Indeed, you're right: there is only one command allowed per id per YAML parsing as a dictionary, so one pkg and one cmd can coexist, but not two cmd.

Answer (score 1):

As one of the users pointed out above, this works in proper order (salt 3000.2)

```
install_borg:
    cmd.run:
        - names: 
            - cd /tmp
            - wget https://github.com/borgbackup/borg/releases/download/1.1.15/borg-linux64
            - mv borg-linux64 /usr/local/bin/borg
            - chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/borg
            - chown root:root /usr/local/bin/borg
            - ln -s /usr/local/bin/borg /usr/bin/borg
        - unless: test -f /usr/bin/borg
```